# jmeter load testing , Parameterization

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing, parameterization

I am running a HTTP request test in jmeter where I send a json input. For example:

```
{ "id":"0", "fieldvalue":"sanket","Source":"todays date" }
```

I need to parametrize this so that for each thread iteration a different value for `id`, `fieldvalue`, `source` is chosen, possibly from a json file only (not CSV file). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible. Here are the options

1. JMeter can read almost any files. Check out the following functions:

   - [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)
   - [_StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)
2. You can also use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to read the file, just use `file` as protocol and UNC path.
3. Values for parametrization can be obtained using [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor). See:

   - [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) - for JSON Path language overview and syntax
   - [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) - for some not obvious scenarios covered